# IRQ affinity handling in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have Linux running as a VM with 2 vCPUs and one interface. For the interface's rx interrupt I have the IRQ affinity set to both the vCPUs (in /proc/../smp_affinity).

How is the interrupt assignment to the CPU done in this case ?

With iperf traffic the combined cpu usage for 2 vCPUs is 100%, with most of it from soft-interrupt handling. At a given instance the split between the 2 vCPUs is random, 30-70, 60-40, 50-50 etc.

If I change the IRQ affinity to one vCPU that CPU goes to 100%.

If the kernel is doing plain round robin between the 2 vCPUs shouldn't the load on both the vCPUs be close to 100% instead of the combined load between 2 vCPUs being 100% ?

Comment: How could one softirq be split in two?

Comment: Obviously it can't be. But IRQs can be assigned to the available CPUs in a round robin manner.